# How can get totalBalanceAmount value from getSavingsInput() and put into (HERE)?

Tags: javascript, dom

How can get **totalBalanceAmount** value from **getSavingsInput()** that i can put into **(HERE)**?

```
function getSavingsInput() {
    let totalBalance = document.getElementById('balance')
    let totalBalanceAmount = parseFloat(totalBalance.value)
    return totalBalanceAmount;
}

document.getElementById('Savings').addEventListener('click',function() {
    let savingInput = getInput('savigns-input') // this is the another function
    let savingsInputAmount = parseFloat(savingInput)
    const savignsAmount = (HERE) % savingsInputAmount;
    const savedAmount =  document.getElementById('saved-amount')
    savedAmount.innerText = savignsAmount;
})
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just call the function?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: yea if I call that function that returns  NaN

Comment: You have at least two spellings of savings here

Comment: function getSavingsInput() {
    let totalBalance = document.getElementById('balance')
    let totalBalanceAmount = parseFloat(totalBalance.value) || 0
    return totalBalanceAmount;
}